# Still cannot watch Netflix despite installing widevine

Tags: raspbian

I have a pi-4 running rpiOS and I installed libwidevinecdm0 in accordance with [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-widevine/) post.

The full upgrade ran properly and I rebooted my machine, I still cannot watch netflix on chromium.

All I get is this screen when trying to play something:

[image]

Widevine doesn't even appear in chrome://components

[image: list of components in chrome://components]

Comment: Is chromium up-to-date? Run `dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W` to see if that Widevine is installed. Please check this [blog](https://blog.vpetkov.net/2020/03/30/raspberry-pi-netflix-one-line-easy-install-along-with-hulu-amazon-prime-disney-plus-hbo-spotify-pandora-and-many-others/) post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is 32-bit Widevine not working on 64-bit Raspian. Here's a [good thread about it](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=329426), which suggest Google will release it in Q3 2022. Here's the [official solution](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-os-64-bit/) from Raspberry Pi, of how to install the 32-bit version of Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this, as this is still a major issue months later.

It seems to me that people should pull together and find a resolution for this... upstream will never really find a nice resolution, where would the money in that be? raspberrypi.stackexchange.com seems like the most logical place to pool information together on this topic.

to start, I feel like all contributers to the topic need to state their hardware, os image, and existing or fresh install.  Then describe what you did, and the results of it.  We can work through this!

I have a raspi 4 8gb, using a fresh install of the native 64bit  raspios_arm64-2021-11-08 from raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm54/images/

after letting raspbian do its updates after a fresh install, I immediately opened a terminal and issued `sudo apt install libwidevinecdm0`

Plenty of websites say "That's it! Ready to stream!" Not so... I still get our favourite Pardon the interruption netflix message indicating no DRM.

Using the address bar of the supplied chromium, I goto chrome://components and don't see widevine.  I need to know where the libraries that I just installed went.  My thinking is that the library is somewhere other than where chromium is looking for it.

`dpkg-query -L libwidevinecdm0 | grep so` reveals it's hiding in /opt/WidevineCdm/_platform_specific/linux_arm/libwidevinecdm.so

With that information, I `cd /usrlib/chromium-browser` and `ln -s /opt/WidevineCdm/_platform_specific/linux_arm/libwidevinecdm.so ./`
I restart the browser, and still no DRM.

I seen somewhere that libwidevine only works on 32 bit.  I flashed a different SD card using rpi-imager using the Official Raspberry PI OS (32) Desktop (Recommended) option.  Plugged it into the raspi, let it update, then opened the console and `sudo apt install libwidevinecdm0` when it was done, I opened the browser, and netflix works.

Some issues I'm already seeing though:  There is a noticeable lag in system response time, even to normal keyboard strokes, on 32b vs 64.

The location of the installed .so file is still the same on 32 vs 64.  So what's different?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo su -
root@raspberrypi:~# cd /
root@raspberrypi:/# find -iname "*widevine*"
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
./opt/WidevineCdm
./opt/WidevineCdm/_platform_specific/linux_arm/libwidevinecdm.so
./usr/share/doc/libwidevinecdm0
./home/pi/configs/widevine.sh
./home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/File System/Plugins/000/application_x-ppapi-widevine-cdm
./home/pi/.config/chromium/WidevineCdm
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libwidevinecdm0.md5sums
./var/lib/dpkg/info/libwidevinecdm0.list
root@raspberrypi:/#
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/117038)

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my answer since this is the *most easy* solution, imho for whom is having this problem.

I had the 32-bit Debian edition from Raspberry Pi running, for say 3 years and WideVine working using the official package for Debian (32-bit) libwidevinecdm0

However, suddenly netflix had sound only and the video was 'black'. My children will not accept the 'sorry dudes' answer.

So, I backed up my documents folder and any important history to a USB drive, and installed the 64 bit version from Raspberry pi using the Imager V1.7.2 and I chose the Raspberry PI OS (64-bit).

After setting my preferred username, region etc, I rebooted, restored the backup data (Documents), I lost *only* my chrome history.

But netflix just works *out of the box*. No installing of plugins (wide vine) required, no reinstalling a 32-bit chrome on a 64-bit OS. Everything runs smooth, and the CPU stays at avg 30%, which is great.
Compared to the previous 32-bit Raspberry PI, I don't see hiccups any more.

For your reference my OS version now shows up like this

> Linux ***** 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023
> aarch64 GNU/Linux
>
> PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)" NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
> VERSION_ID="11" VERSION="11 (bullseye)" VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
> ID=debian HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org